# Understanding shared centimorgans if siblings have child?

Tags: dna

If siblings have a child together how many centimorgans would that child share with their 1st cousin from the same blood line?

Answer (score 3):

A child gets exactly 50% of its DNA from one specific parent, and approximately 25% of its DNA from any one specific grandparent.

In the case of two siblings having a child (I hope this is either a theoretical question or happened unknowingly), then the child would only have two grandparents, because their father's father and mother's father are the same person, and their father's mother and mother's mother are the same person. Thus from each of their two grandparents, they would get on average 50%.

Therefore they would get twice the expected amount of match that standard first cousins get (average 869 cM, range 533 - 1379 cM). Twice that amount is equivalent to what an aunt or uncle get (average 1744 cM, range 1301 - 2193 cM) as shown on page 2 of [Blaine Bettinger's Shared CM Project - Version 2.0](http://thegeneticgenealogist.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Shared-cM-Project-Version-2.pdf).